# pyDev-Eclipse: how to delay the hints

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

When moving the mouse cursor over the python source in Pydev/eclipse, a hint-window emerges with short documentation of the function or variable hovered over. While in itself this is a handy function, it is way to fast and causing me difficulties to position the cursor for inserting code. How can I increase the delay and so, reduced the number of hints?

Comment: pyDev has way too few configuration options.  I guess the only way could be to patch the source :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no option for that... as adding it should be simple, I'd suggest implementing that and providing a pull request to PyDev (see: http://pydev.org/developers.html). Or you can simply create a feature request for that, but I don't think it'll be considered a high-priority feature to implement, so, it might take a while until it's done.

Comment: Well, it's still a problem in 2018, so I guess you're right :)

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know how to increase the delay, here's a throwing-the-baby-out-with-the-bathwater workaround:

In Preferences/Pydev/Editor/Hover, uncheck `Show docstrings?`.  Then you won't get any popups when hovering.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system wide setting.

On Windows it can be modifying by editing registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\MouseHoverTime`.

Comment: There's no such entry at at that location (nor anywhere else in the registry). Adding it makes no difference. Could this solution depend on the version of Windows?